# How do I use Font Awesome (4.7) with Nativescript (3.4.2) with Angular (5)

Tags: android, font-awesome, nativescript, angular5

Hopefully this is a simple question, but it has me stumped at the moment.

I am creating a Nativescript application for Android using an Angular 5/TS tabbed template, and am trying to integrate Font Awesome icons into the project. The problem is, every single icon shows up as what appears to be an envelope/placeholder instead of the actual icon. Is there something that I am missing that is required for this to work on Android? 
See the screenshots below.

[image]

Here's what I have gathered from various tutorials and guides online:

- The ".ttf" font file needs to be in "../app/fonts/" folder.
- A css class needs to be created with a font-family matching the font filename.
- The css class needs to be applied to the desired tag in template file, and the text attribute needs to contain the unicode for the icon.
- Most/all of the tutorials were using iOS instead of Android (I am using Android), and they had .css instead of .scss files. Does this have something to do with it?

Despite doing all of the above, I can't get this to work. Here is the setup I am trying:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The same thing seems to happen with just a plain old label:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard `FontAwesome.ttf` instead of the web font variant.
Using SCSS instead of CSS does not change anything - [this NativeScreipt template](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-master-detail-ng) is, in fact, implementing `FontAwesome` with SCSS.

The only difference is that the template uses not the `-webfont` but the `FontAwesome.ttf` and in the respective SCSS class the font is referred with its file name 

`.fa {
    font-family: "FontAwesome"
}`

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll give this a shot later on today and respond back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin which is helpful in using any / multiple font icons.

https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ngx-fonticon

Comment: Thanks Manoj, I have tried this plugin (including their instructions) but have not been successful.

Comment: At least I can confirm I'm using that plugin successfully with font awesome and icon moon fonts.